# Retrieve path param AbstractPhaseInterceptor cxf

Tags: java, rest, cxf, interceptor

i am developing a rest webservice with this structure

http://localhost:8080/context/login/{user}/{password}

and example of this request is

http://localhost:8080/context/login/admin/admin

i have configured an AbstractPhaseInterceptor in the applicationContext.xml of my spring application. And the interceptor class is

public class TokenInInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor {

```
public TokenInInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.READ);
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) {

}
```

}

i would like to retrieve the parameters user and password form the object message in the handleMessage method, but i can`t found where it is.

Anyone know how can i retrieve that parameters?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
UriInfo uriInfo = new UriInfoImpl(message);
MetadataMap<String, String> metadataMap = (MetadataMap<String, String>) uriInfo.getPathParameters();
User user = metadataMap.getFirst("user");
String password = metadataMap.getFirst("password");
```